# How to capitalize the first letter in a MaterialSearchView?

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I've implemented [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) in a fragment and it works fine. Now I want to make the first letter of each word capital. This is what I have tried:

```
<com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/material_search_view"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"/> //Doesn't work
```

But for some reason, it doesn't work. Please help me with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override the `attr` of the `EditText` of `MaterialSeachView` like this:

```
MaterialSearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view); //inflate with your MaterialSeachView ID 
final EditText editText = searchView.findViewById(com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.R.id.searchTextView);
editText.setInputType(InputType.REQUIRED_TYPE); // replace REQUIRED_TYPE with your needed inputType
```

Comment: Maybe you can also help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322954/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-text-in-suggestions-in-materialsearchview) one. Thanks