# How to increase the size of the text in suggestions in MaterialSearchView?

Tags: android, searchview, android-search

I've implemented [MaterialSearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) in a fragment and it works fine. Now I want to increase the size of the text in suggestions. How can I do that? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the developers/contributors of this lib has provided an way to do this without the need to fork and edit the lib.

Anyway, for me the easiest way to do what I want is to edit the lib. for your case, if you want edit the text attributes of the `textview` of suggestions, you may fork the lib and edit the layout named `suggest_item` as  it is the layout used by the adapter that shows the suggestions.

Links [this](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView/blob/6fa22bcc51b517c5ba239b10571089f4ceec550c/library/src/main/java/com/miguelcatalan/materialsearchview/SearchAdapter.java#L101) and [this](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView/tree/develop/library/src/main/res/layout)

---

if this does not suit you, you can always add new issue and/or question to the developers/contributors of the lib on the their repo's issue tracker on github, follow [this link](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView/issues)

---

**EDIT:** for your question in comments on how to handle click on suggestions:

The developers/contributors of the lib has provided a public method that you can use to add a click listener, it is named `setOnItemClickListener`

See [this](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView/blob/53e163c90da5d25b0d88aa182f91027487bee043/library/src/main/java/com/miguelcatalan/materialsearchview/MaterialSearchView.java#L395) for full method code